# How to avoid listing all spark slaves' IP addresses in a subnetwork in slaves file?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to start all spark slave nodes in a subnet 10.100.10.0/24, but I do not want to list all the IP addresses in the slaves file. Is there any convenient way to do this?